Can I add a city field to the shipping zone with hooks and make it work like a country state?
Method 1: There is already a country, state and post code in the existing zone settings. I can check the city field instead of the post code during checkout.
`public static function get_zone_matching_package( $package ) {
$country          = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['country'] ) );
$state            = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['state'] ) );
$postcode         = wc_normalize_postcode( wc_clean( $package['destination']['postcode'] ) );
$cache_key        = WC_Cache_Helper::get_cache_prefix( 'shipping_zones' ) . 'wc_shipping_zone_' . md5( sprintf( '%s+%s+%s', $country, $state, $postcode ) );
$matching_zone_id = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'shipping_zones' );
    if ( false === $matching_zone_id ) {
        $data_store       = WC_Data_Store::load( 'shipping-zone' );
        $matching_zone_id = $data_store->get_zone_id_from_package( $package );
        wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $matching_zone_id, 'shipping_zones' );
    }

    return new WC_Shipping_Zone( $matching_zone_id ? $matching_zone_id : 0 );
}`

Method 2(I made this solution and it works):
I changed 2 core files and it works, but could I do this with hooks?
Creating city like country and state in class-wc-shipping-zones.php and css-wc-shipping-zone.php structure
WC_Shipping_Zone (class-wc-shipping-zone.php):
Represents a single shipping zone and manages information about that zone (for example, shipping methods, zone name).
WC_Shipping_Zones (class-wc-shipping-zones.php):
$city             = strtoupper( wc_clean( $package['destination']['city'] ) );
....
I wanted to know if it is possible with hook from a more maintainable perspective
